# asking permission on flutter creates new instance of page after accepting

Tags: flutter, dart

For my flutter app, I have to request permission for the camera feed.
For this, I use the permission_handler module for this.

after calling the code below and accepting the permission a new instance of the same page is created and the old page still exists. 
how can I stop the system from creating the new page?

```
 Future<void> askPermissionBeforeHand() async{
    final PermissionHandler _permissionHandler = PermissionHandler();
    final permissionStatus = await _permissionHandler.checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera);
    if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      var result = await _permissionHandler.requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]);
    }
  }
```

---

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:zorg_nl/core/utils/ui_utils.dart';
import 'package:zorg_nl/l10n/ionicons.dart';
import 'package:zorg_nl/locator.dart';
import 'package:zorg_share/colors.dart';
import 'package:zorg_share/components/molecules/header_icon_molecule.dart';
import 'package:zorg_nl/ui/widgets/wp_rounded_button.dart';

class RegistrationValidationInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  void onFindHealthCareProviders(BuildContext context) {
    Locator.analytics().logSelectContent(contentType: 'button', itemId: 'registration_search_providers');
    UiUtils.navigateByTag(context: context,pushPath: '/providers');
  }

  Future<void> onHelp() async {
    await UiUtils.sendHelpAnalytics('registration_provider');
    await UiUtils.openWebsite('http://www.zorg.nl');
  }

  Future<void> askPermissionBeforeHand() async{
    final PermissionHandler _permissionHandler = PermissionHandler();
    final permissionStatus = await _permissionHandler.checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera);
    if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      var result = await _permissionHandler.requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Locator.analytics().setCurrentScreen(screenName: 'VerifyHealthCareProvider');
    askPermissionBeforeHand();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: colorWhite,
      key: scaffoldKey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(bottom: 10,
                left: 0, right: 0,child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              materialCareButton(context,
                  text: 'register_provider_care_provider',
                  iconData: IonIcons.ios_navigate,
                  color: colorPrimaryColor,
                  onPressed:() => onFindHealthCareProviders(context)),
              Container(height: 5),
              materialCareButton(context,
                  text: 'generic_need_help',
                  textColor: colorPrimaryColor,
                  onPressed: onHelp),
            ])),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 40, 16, 0),
              child: HeaderIcon(
                title: 'register_provider_title',
                subHeader: 'register_provider_sub_header',
                icon: IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: 'material'), // policy
              ),
            ),
          ],)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more of your code to understand, a runnable code would be helpful

Comment: there is not much more code. the page itself is a stateless widget

Comment: there must be something, where this function is being called, without any further information, how can anyone help you?

Comment: this is the full widget

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the permission method and if you disable the calling to the method on the build function, the problem does not arise?

Comment: the problem does not arise if I already have the permission. the dialog creates the problem in this scenario.
after accepting the permission in the dialog a new instance of this widget is created.

Comment: Maybe try to call `askPermissionBeforeHand` in the `initState` method instead of the build method?

Comment: I agree with @cumul , use stateful widget and call ask for permission in the initState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem a few weeks ago but forgot to post the answer.
The problem wasn't what you would expect and was the continuation of a problem from another page. 
On this page, I used the `WidgetsBindingObserver` to listen for changes in the lifecycle of the app and moved on to the next page with a Push if the validation was correct on the app's resume lifecycle. As you know previous pages in flutter are not directly cleaned or put on the stack like in Android. They are still alive and just below the currently visible page. So when I asked flutter to show a Dialog the `OnResume` function was called on my previous page and pushed a new Page to the screen and after this pushed the Dialog.

The solution for this was to Pop my last page and Push the new page afterward. In my case, I didn't need the page anymore. If you still need the page you can remove the listener on the `WidgetsBindingObserver` and reattach it when you Pop back to the page.